# Sqlacodegen showing Argspec not found

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlacodegen

can anyone please help me with it. I was trying to use sqlacodegen with postgresql to autogenerate the database models from my database, but it is constantly showing me this import error

```
>sqlacodegen postgresql://postgres:j1234@localhost:4040/db1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\sqlacodegen.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlacodegen\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sqlacodegen.codegen import CodeGenerator
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlacodegen\codegen.py", line 9, in <module>
    from inspect import ArgSpec
ImportError: cannot import name 'ArgSpec' from 'inspect' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py)
```

i am working with python 3.11, postgresql, sqlalchemy 2.0.15, and sqlacodegen 2.3.0

I want to autogenerate database models from my database for my fastapi. I am also open to any kind of sqlacodegen alternatives

Comment: `ArgSpec` was removed in python3.11, you have to either use 3.10 or wait for `sqlacodegen` to fix it

Comment: Thanks man, youre right. I installed 3.10 version of python and now it is working just fine... God bless you

Comment: What exactly does ArgSpec get replaced with? No idea even what it did in the first place... some sort of reflection capability?

Comment: [sqlacodegen guidance](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/issues/239) is to use the pre release version ```pip install --pre sqlacodegen```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue as well. The problem arises because ArgSpec has been removed in Python 3.11.

The solution is to open the `/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py` file in your text editor. Then, delete the line that includes `from inspect import ArgSpec` at line 9. Additionally, remove lines 486 and 488, replacing them with `return False`, and then run your command again. It should work without any issues.

Comment: It doesn't work. It showed me a new error: 

File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main   File "<frozen runpy>", line .......................    return __import__("MySQLdb")            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Answer (score 2):

To add onto what others have mentioned, [SQLAcodegen-v2](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen-v2/) doesn't have this issue and runs fine on Python 3.11 (with SQLAlchemy 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, sqlacodegen is not compatible with 3.11.
So as a workaround (Just like @yusufusta suggested)

- venv/Lib/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py
- delete ArgSpec
- change the following functions by these:

```html
    def _getargspec_init(method):
        try:
            if hasattr(inspect, 'getfullargspec'):
                fullargspec = inspect.getfullargspec(method)
                return {
                    'args': fullargspec.args,
                    'varargs': fullargspec.varargs,
                    'varkw': fullargspec.varkw,
                    'defaults': fullargspec.defaults
                }
            else:
                argspec = inspect.getargspec(method)
                return {
                    'args': argspec.args,
                    'varargs': argspec.varargs,
                    'varkw': argspec.varkw,
                    'defaults': argspec.defaults
                }
        except TypeError:
            if method is object.__init__:
                return {
                    'args': ['self'],
                    'varargs': None,
                    'varkw': None,
                    'defaults': None
                }
            else:
                return {
                    'args': ['self'],
                    'varargs': 'args',
                    'varkw': 'kwargs',
                    'defaults': None
                }

    @classmethod
    def render_column_type(cls, coltype):
        args = []
        kwargs = OrderedDict()
        argspec = cls._getargspec_init(coltype.__class__.__init__)
        defaults = dict(zip(argspec['args'][-len(argspec['defaults'] or ()):],
                            argspec['defaults'] or ()))
        missing = object()
        use_kwargs = False
        for attr in argspec['args'][1:]:
            # Remove annoyances like _warn_on_bytestring
            if attr.startswith('_'):
                continue

            value = getattr(coltype, attr, missing)
            default = defaults.get(attr, missing)
            if value is missing or value == default:
                use_kwargs = True
            elif use_kwargs:
                kwargs[attr] = repr(value)
            else:
                args.append(repr(value))

        if argspec['varargs'] and hasattr(coltype, argspec['varargs']):
            varargs_repr = [repr(arg) for arg in getattr(coltype, argspec['varargs'])]
            args.extend(varargs_repr)

        if isinstance(coltype, Enum) and coltype.name is not None:
            kwargs['name'] = repr(coltype.name)

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            args.append('{}={}'.format(key, value))

        rendered = coltype.__class__.__name__
        if args:
            rendered += '({0})'.format(', '.join(args))

        return rendered
```